# Can I add inline comments in peers.txt?

Tags: parity, configuration

My peers.txt file for my private parity network looks like this.

```
enode://1111-redacted-6eaf@172.0.0.1:30303
enode://2222-redacted-6eaf@172.0.0.2:30303
enode://3333-redacted-6eaf@172.0.0.2:30303
```

Is there any way to add inline comments for each line to remind me what each node is in my private network. I tried

```
# This is airport X node
```

but parity rejected it on startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like it at present, though IMO it'd be a sensible addition to allow it. Perhaps open a [new ticket](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/new) with the Parity folks.

The code is in [`configuration.rs`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/8d04dffe697e9b41f9893487e220ec30623885e2/parity/configuration.rs#L656). The only check it runs is using [`is_valid_node_url()`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/8404edb656693270ec1cd3956d204f625d28ec7c/util/network/src/node_table.rs#L352), which doesn't allow anything except a URL.

```
    match self.args.flag_reserved_peers {
        Some(ref path) => {
            let mut buffer = String::new();
            let mut node_file = File::open(path).map_err(|e| format!("Error opening reserved nodes file: {}", e))?;
            node_file.read_to_string(&mut buffer).map_err(|_| "Error reading reserved node file")?;
            let lines = buffer.lines().map(|s| s.trim().to_owned()).filter(|s| !s.is_empty()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
            if let Some(invalid) = lines.iter().find(|s| !is_valid_node_url(s)) {
                return Err(format!("Invalid node address format given for a boot node: {}", invalid));
            }
            Ok(lines)
        },
        None => Ok(Vec::new())
    }
```

Comment: Issue opened: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/6004

Comment: Now available in v1.6.9!